# Get ID from cURL to next the process

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm using CURL to process the data readings from the URL. Then I want to get the **movie_id** of each link and do the next process with the URL that will receive the **movie_id** so that I get the data in more detail.

My cURL code :

```
<?php
$url="http://m.21cineplex.com/";
function bacaHTML($url){
    $data = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9850; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.115 Mobile Safari/534.11+");
    curl_setopt($data,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($data,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt'); 
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $hasil = curl_exec($data);
    curl_close($data);
    return $hasil;
}

$html= bacaHTML($url);

$html=str_replace(array("\r","\t","\n"),"",$html);
preg_match_all("/<ol id=\"menu_ol\">(.*?)<\/ol>/",$html,$raw);

echo "<p>Now Playing</p>".$raw[0][0]."<p>Coming Soon".$raw[0][1]."Movie News".$raw[0][2]
```

How do I separate the **ID** so that I can make the next process?

Ex : [Next process with ID](http://m.21cineplex.com/gui.list_schedule?sid=&movie_id=137ASS&find_by=1&order=1)

Comment: How the URL looks like? That's just `GET` method isn't it?

Comment: Since see your sample URL, you simply get the Id with `$_GET['sid']` or `$_GET['movie_id']`.... Depending how much your ID that you send via URL.